# Multiday tasks on Calendar ignore work hours

Tags: tasks, sharepoint-calendar

```
We have tasks that begin on one day and complete on another day.  For
```

example, we start a 4 hour task at 3pm March 8, stop at 5pm, then restart at 
8am March 9 and end it 10am.  We don't work over night.

```
SharePoint calendar shows the task running all night for a total of 19
```

hours.  This makes our Calendar view ugly and misleading.  How can we get 
SharePoint to respect our normal work hours.  In other words, only show Mar 8, 
3pm to 5pm, and Mar 9, 8am to 10am?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you find anyway of doing this? having the same issue with our site.